# When the client is closed where does the server println() method send

Tags: java, sockets

It is the simple java socket client/server model(the server send data and the client receive) . The question is that when the client closed where the server send the data(the server do not detect whether the client is closed) .I know the server can detect and close the stream,but i want to know where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the protocol you use.

If you use TCP the Socket of the server will throw a exception when the Socket of the client is closed or you try to send something after the Socket of the client is closed.

If you use UDP the Socket will not detect whether the Client is still listening on the port and  sends the data anyway. On the client's machine it is just ignored.

Comment: Thanks you.Here I use TCP and I know that in C language it will throw a exception when the client is closed .What confused me is that in java use TCP when then client is closed the server is still send data,and where it send ?

Comment: The data gets still sent to the same port, but since the Socket is closed it gets ignored.